# Entering every value of the set() function in python into a new line in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, time, nltk, newline

I have 100,000 words as the result of a set function in Python 3 NLTK.

```
word_list1_total=set(words1_total)
```

I want to write `word_list1_total` to a csv file. Then I want to open that csv file along with other similar csv files and perform word_tokenize() and set() functions on the combinations of those csv files. The problem is I can easily write `word_list1_total` by doing this

```
with open('C:\\My_folder\\csv_file1.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            writer.writerow(word_list1_total)
```

However, the `csv_file1.csv` file that is then created has say a size of 7 MB with 100,000 words in just 1 line in a csv file. That csv file then becomes impossible to use because of the length of that line.

How to make this file usable? Had the 100,000 words been in 100,000 lines with 1 word each, then, I think, it would have been more usable. Is there any way in which while creating this csv file, I can write every word to a new line in the csv file, so that instead of looking like this:

```
word_1,word_2,word_3,...word_100000
```

it looks like this

```
word_1,
word_2,
word_3,...
word_100000
```

I am writing my first Python programme. So please help.

Comment: Why do you want to write it to a csv file? There are many different file formats you could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through your list word by word and write each word in a separate row instead. Using a `for` loop, this would look as follows:

```
with open('C:\\My_folder\\csv_file1.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            for word in word_list1_total:
                writer.writerow([word])
```

Edit: Note that each word is wrapped in a list in order to prevent each individual character being saved in a separate column.

Comment: Your suggestions create a file where every row/ line has one word. However, the problem is in every line/row, the words are no longer intact but have become separated letter-wise. So, instead of getting `cat` I am getting `c,a,t`.

Comment: I see. I think this would be fixable by wrapping each individual word into a list, e.g. `writer.writerow([word])`. Otherwise, the strings will be treated as iterables and each letter would be written to an individual column.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It has done what I wanted it to do. The csv files are also very usable now even if they have more than 1.6 million rows/lines.